# How to use paths with spaces in automator shell script?

Tags: automator

I have an Automator workflow which should set the CreationDate of the selected file to a date which I want to enter. Unfortunately my path have spaces. Therefore it doesn'w work.
I've tried several variants like:

```
SetFile -d \"$1 12:00:00\" "$@2"
SetFile -d \"$1 12:00:00\" \"$@2\"
SetFile -d \"$1 12:00:00\" '$@2'
SetFile -d \"$1 12:00:00\" \'$@2\'
```

The path is like follows:
/Users/simon/Documents/Steuern/Steuern 2021/Scan_000775.pdf

The shell I use is ZSH with oh-my-zsh installed.

This is the Workflow I have:

- Ask for Finder-Object
- Get value of variable
- Ask for Text input
- Set value of variable
- Ask for value of variable
- execute shell script: "SetFile -d "$1 12:00:00" "$@2""

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to write the shellscript to use pathnames with spaces?
That would be very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding right, you want:

```
SetFile -d "$1 12:00:00" "${@:2}"
```

Explanation: escaping quotes prevents them from acting like quotes (it turns them into normal characters); in this case, you want them to function as quotes, so you shouldn't escape them. Also, `"$@2"` doesn't get the arguments starting at `$2`, it gets *all* of the arguments, and sticks a "2" to the end of the last one. If you want all the arguments except the first, use `"${@:2}"` instead.

Comment: Dear Gordon

Thanks for your answer and explanation.
Yes then it should be this command which I want. But it doesn't work.
There is no error message but the output is just:("") and the date of the file is not changed.

Comment: Try adding the command `exec 2>~/automator-trace.txt; set -x` at the beginning (before the `SetFile` command), and see what the execution trace shows. Note that it'll generally use single-quotes around arguments that have spaces or other funny characters (even though it's double-quotes in the script).

Comment: Hio Gordon. Thanks again. Hmm this is weird. Unfortunately I've deleted the Automator file. Therefore I had to recreate it. As template I've took the picture I've posted and created it exactly as it was before. Except with the difference that it works now. I also added your suggested command. Cool I asked myself some times how to get a trace/logfile. The output is this: `code` +zsh:2> SetFile -d '08/01/22 12:00:00' '/Users/simon/Documents/Steuern/Steuern 2022/2022_02_10 - 2022 - Provisorisch - Staats und Gemeindesteuern.pdf' `code`

Comment: And please apologize the bad formatting. I'm not yet familiar with the reduced markdown functions in comments. So I tried around but the 5min. for editing the comment was already up.